# how to notify superuser to change the category of another user after he submits a form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django project with multiple types of users. At the base is a business user and he can upgrade to a 'professional' user or a 'novice' user.
 I want him to fill a form with his details and then any of the superuser or selected user shall get a notification to be able to view his form in a  listview of all others who applied and allow them or reject them "professional" user status from the templates itself.

i have tried of using Boolean values to assign with each user to their status and then other user can change that Boolean value but it did not work.

Any references to such permissions or giving powers to users to give other users powers shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some code?